# CUDA 4.0 using pointers within kernels - error

Tags: pointers, cuda, gpu

my question is as follows:

I wish to use a kernel in two ways.

- I use an array `d_array` that has been copied over using `cudaMemcpy`, i.e. through

```
cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(d_array, array,  100*sizeof(double),
                         cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

Or

- I input a double `mydouble` directly i.e. `double mydouble = 3;`

If I input the array I simply use (which works fine):

```
kernel<<<1, 100>>>(d_array, 100, output);
```

If I input a double I use (which **doesn't** work fine!!!!):

```
kernel<<<1, 100>>>(&mydouble, 1, output);
```

My kernel is listed below:

```
___global___ void kernel(double * d_array, int size_d_array, double * output)
{
  double a;

  if (size_d_array == 100) 
    {output[threadIdx.x] = d_array[threadIdx.x];}

  else
    {output a[threadIdx.x] = d_array[0];} 
}
```

Comment: Is that the exact code you're having? Because `kernel(d_array, 100)<<<1, 100>>>;` should at the very least be `kernel<<<1, 100>>>(d_array, 100);`

Comment: Lol, sorry its psuedo-code... but the question remains.

Comment: Please post your actual code with the actual kernel call and memory allocations.

Comment: I would *BUT* the question contains all the info necessary. My question is simply how can I use the kernel using method 2

Comment: Post pseudo code and expect only an pseudo answer. Post actual code and you might get somewhere.

Comment: this is actual code, I rewrote now!

Comment: Do you have two kernels named `kernel`? Because they have a different number of arguments. (If not, once again make sure to post real code) And where does `mydouble` come from?

Comment: Are you really asking "why can't a kernel operate directly on a host pointer"?

Comment: @talonmies Seems like it. gamma123 for the exact same reason as you moved your array from host to device, you can't give a host pointer to a kernel. That simply won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double aDouble = 3;
double *myDouble = &double;
```

If you do the above in host code, then myDouble is a pointer to host memory.  That is why you can't pass it directly to a device kernel (a pointer is a pointer, whether it points to an array or a scalar value!).

However in CUDA 4.0 you can call cudaHostRegister on the host pointer and if your system supports [unified virtual addressing](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_0/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html), then you can pass it to the kernel.  If it does not, then you can call [cudaHostRegister](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_0/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g36b9fe28f547f28d23742e8c7cd18141.html#g36b9fe28f547f28d23742e8c7cd18141) with appropriate flags and then [cudaHostGetDevicePointer](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_0/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_ga475419a9b21a66036029d5001ea908c.html#ga475419a9b21a66036029d5001ea908c) to get a pointer you *can* pass to the device kernel.  See the CUDA documentation on